# retrieve data from modal in Ionic2

Tags: typescript

I have a page which has a button that once is clicked creates a modal.

Now I want to set a variable inside my modal and pass it back to the page with that button once the modal has been closed.

This is how I tried (I removed boilerplate code):

**modal.ts**

```
myVar:string;
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.myVar = "Hello";

}
// when modal is being closed
onCancel(){
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.myVar);
    }
```

**pageWithButton.ts**

```
varFromModal:string;
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

  // I get this error here: Error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
    this.viewCtrl.onDismiss(data => { 
            this.varFromModal = data;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant write code directly in your class:

```
class YourClassName {

    varFromModal:string;
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

    // YOU CANT WRITE CODE HERE !!
    // PUT IT IN A FUNCTION OR CONSTRUCTOR OR WHEREVER ..
    this.viewCtrl.onDismiss(data => { 
        this.varFromModal = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I moved it inside the constructor, now I get a this error: Error TS2341: Property 'onDismiss' is private and only accessible within class 'ViewController'. Do you have some example that shows how to pass data from modal to a page?

Comment: I don't know much about Ionic, but you could use an Angular2 service for it. Inside of your modal put data into the service and then you can access that data anywhere else.. but i am sure there is an Ionic way too..

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. This helped me: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/passing-data-in-from-modal/61051/4